# MVC: Send parameters to Action in Controller with Bootstrap button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, button, model-view-controller

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateMaterial", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, Model.MaterialId))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary custom" value="Derivate Material" />
    }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateMaterial(int? matId)
        {
            if (matId == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        //do something here
        }
```

The *Id* I send its always null. How do i change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Model.MaterialId` should be a form element:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateMaterial", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MaterialId)

     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary custom" value="Derivate Material" />
}
```

Additionally, you should change your action definition and make it accept the type of your model, instead of a `int?`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateMaterial(MyModelType model)
{
     if (model.matId == null)
     {
         return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
     }
     //do something here
}
```

Comment: @Html.EditorFor places an input text in the View. I want to be able to automatically send the Id to the Controller. I'm in the "Detail" View of a specific Material and I already know the MaterialId because of the model.

Comment: @Aoren, you need a hidden input for that. I updated my answer.

Comment: Q: I'm sending an object of (in the case of your answer) "MyModelType" with all the specs from the Material in the View or is it just an integer?

Comment: @Aoren it really depends on what you're trying to accomplish. If you just need to send a single id, you'd be better of with AJAX or even an action link. If you want to use a form, then posting a model would be appropriate.